# Sort models by number of occurrences

Tags: django, orm, count

The question has already been asked multiple times but I haven't been able to make my code works. Anyway, let's say I have a blog, with blog posts:

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):  # This class doesn't really matter
    author = models.ForeignKey(myUser)
    text = models.TextField()
```

It happens that I log visits on each blog post using another model:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField()
    # I log different types of activities, hence the choice
    action_id = models.IntegerField(choices=ACTIVITY_ACTIONS)
    object_id = models.CharField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

What I want is to get the most visitied blog posts since a precise date, ordered by their number of views. What I'm doing right now (in the activity manager):

```
def get_blogposts_most_viewed_since(self, date):
    # I get all related activities (blog posts views since date)
    activities = Activity.objects.since(date).filter(action_id=BLOGPOST_VIEW)

    # I get all blogposts' ids
    blogpost_ids = events.values('object_id')

    # I get all blogposts ordered by their number of views:
    blogposts = BlogPost.objects.filter(id__in=blogpost_ids)\
                 .annotate(nb_views=Count('id')).order_by('-nb_views')
    return blogposts
```

This doesn't work. I made some tests: I create three blog posts, blogpost_a is viewed twice, blogpost_b is viewed once and blogpost_c doesn't get any views. When I call the `get_blogposts_most_viewed_since` I do get blogpost_a and blogpost_b but in what seems to be a random_order.

I tried to do some debugging with:

```
for blogpost in blogposts:
    print blogpost.nb_views
```

Both blogposts (a and b) have `nb_views == 1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are counting on "id" which is always 1 when the id is unique. You will have to link blogpost and activity via foreignkey for example and count on that relation.

Comment: All right, fair enough. The thing is I don't want to use ForeignKeys for Activity because the object can be a blogpost or something else. And it has been decided that GenericForeignKeys are not performant enough. Is there another way? I mean, blogpost_ids contains exactly the info I need, is there a "Django" way to use it?

Comment: No need for Generic Foreign Keys, just link them with a foreign key on your Activity Model (i.e.:blogpost=models.ForeignKey(BlogPost).

Comment: I must not have been clear enough: activities log a lot of different things, users looking at blog posts, users commenting on blog posts etc. Meaning that `object_id` can contain the id of a blog post or something else. Hence I cannot use a "simple" ForeignKey to a blogpost.

Comment: [Generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I know, I know (and I agree that it would most probably solve my problem). But the thinking heads above me have deemed that GenericForeignKeys are not performant enough.

Comment: @PierreMourlanne I don't think those heads are doing enough thinking. If generic relations are not performant enough, implementing your own cut-down version using a list of IDs is certainly not going to be any better.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'll try to get the message through :p Well thanks everyone, I guess I'll have to do some convincing to be able to use Generic Relations.

Comment: @PierreMourlanne i think you could use "blogpost_ids = events.values_list('object_id')" and count occurences of each id in the resulting list

Comment: @CrowbarKZ I know I can work something out, for example using your solution. I'm looking for a 'Django way' to solve my problem.